# add property to User Profile SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer

I need to do a display template that shows an employee's list with name, department, photo and birthday. For this I'm trying to use the user profile service, it gives me everything except the birthday.

[image]

my question is how do I add this field birthday or property to the user profile ?

I'm really new working with SharePoint if someone can help me I'll appreciate so much

thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to login on the admin center with admin accounts.

- Sign in to Office 365 with your SharePoint Online admin account.
- Go to the SharePoint admin center.
- Click User Profiles.
- Under People, choose Manage User Properties.
- On the Manage Properties page, select New Property.
- On the Add Profile Property page, in the Property Settings section,
  in the Name text box, type a name to be used by the User Profile
  Service application for the profile property. The Name must be
  unique, but the Display Name does not have to be unique.

You can follow the below documents for more information.
[Add and edit user profile properties](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-edit-user-profile-properties-85091402-737F-4BB9-99A7-BC5F194502A8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)